# How to get path extension in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

If I have a file name like this how do I get the path extension?

http://example.com/image.png?key=value

If I use `-pathExtension` for `NSString` it returns `jpg?key=value`.

I want to get the true extension from the path so just `jpg`.

Comment: Treat it as an URL, not as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try your code in swift. It works fine.

```
let url = URL(string: "http://example.com/image.png?key=value")
print(url?.pathExtension) //Optional("png")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/image.png?key=value"];
NSString *ext = [[url lastPathComponent] pathExtension];
NSLog(@"%@", ext) ;  // png
```